# ¿Por qué no se puede pasar la fecha como parametro?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedure

Tengo que pasar una fecha como parámetro desde c# hacia un procedure en oracle
pero me muestra error de mes invalido.
Este es el metodo en c#

```
public void EliminarDataAntigua(int codEstacion, string fecha)
        {

            //OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(ConexcionDA.CadenaConexion());
            try
            {

                //var fech = fecha.Split('/');
                //string nuevafech = fech[0] + "-" + ((fech[1].ToString() == "01") ? "Jan" : "Feb") + "-" + fech[2];
                OracleConnection conexion = new OracleConnection(ConexcionDA.CadenaConexion());


                //OracleCommand comando = new OracleCommand("delete from VENTA_DETALLADA_TEST where COD_ESTACION = "+ codEstacion + " and FECHA_PROCESO = '"+nuevafech+"'", conexion);

                OracleCommand comando = new OracleCommand("DELETE_DATA_ANTIGUA", conexion);
                comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comando.Parameters.Add("estacion", OracleType.VarChar).Value = codEstacion;
                comando.Parameters.Add("fecha", OracleType.VarChar).Value = fecha;
                conexion.Open();
                int a = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conexion.Close();
                conexion.Dispose();
                comando.Dispose();

                //return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string errror = e.ToString();
                //return true;
            }

        }
```

y este el el procedure :

```
create OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETE_DATA_ANTIGUA(
estacion VARCHAR2,
fecha varchar2
)
 IS
 BEGIN

 declare
  stmt varchar2(2000) := 'delete from VENTA_DETALLADA_TEST where COD_ESTACION ='||estacion||' and FECHA_PROCESO in ('''||fecha||''')' ;
----  --stmt2 varchar2(2000):= 'GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY USER_DIR TO PUBLIC;';
 begin
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
----   --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt2;
end;

-- delete from VENTA_DETALLADA_TEST where COD_ESTACION = estacion and FECHA_PROCESO = (select TO_DATE(fecha,'DD/MM/YY') from dual);
commit;


 END;
```

el error en c# es el siguiente

```
{"ORA-01843: not a valid month\nORA-06512: at \"COMERCIAL.DELETE_DATA_ANTIGUA\", line 12\nORA-06512: at line 1\n"}
```

Los campos que se pasan por ejemplo sin 9971 y "01/01/22/018"

¿Cuál es el problema con la fecha?
gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo más seguro que la configuración regional de tu aplicativo y de tu base de datos sea diferente. Un ejemplo es que tu aplicativo tenga como región España y tu base de datos esté configurada como americana.
Para ello te recomiendo modifiques tu llamada al procedimiento almacenado para que en el parámetro `fecha` reciba una fecha en formato YYYYMMDD de esta manera

```
comando.Parameters.Add("fecha", OracleType.VarChar).Value = fecha.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

y modifiques tu procedimiento así

```
create OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETE_DATA_ANTIGUA(
estacion VARCHAR2,
fecha varchar2
)
 IS
 BEGIN

 declare
  stmt varchar2(2000) := 'delete from VENTA_DETALLADA_TEST where COD_ESTACION ='||estacion||' and FECHA_PROCESO in (TO_DATE('''|| fecha ||''', ''YYYYMMDD''))' ;
----  --stmt2 varchar2(2000):= 'GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY USER_DIR TO PUBLIC;';
 begin
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
----   --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt2;
end;

-- delete from VENTA_DETALLADA_TEST where COD_ESTACION = estacion and FECHA_PROCESO = (select TO_DATE(fecha,'DD/MM/YY') from dual);
commit;


 END;
```

Comment: También te recomiendo no conformar una cadena para escribir la consulta a tu procedimiento almacenado, ejecuta directamente la sentencia